# Programmatically call special print driver functions

Tags: winapi, printing

I want to programatically call the special functions in the Maintenance tab of my Canon Pixma's Printer Properties (in Windows):

[image: Printer Properties Window]

I'm specifically after any .Net or Win32 methods that I should be looking to use, but I'm happy to hear alternative methods that might work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the clean was sent to the printer via print spooler as a 'maintenance' job. Thanks to [this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659857/139388) I was able to capture the data sent to the printer.

I then sent raw commands to the printer as per the instructions on [this MS page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091).

(Unfortunately, I discovered this after doing hack with printui.dll,PrintUIEntry and various FindWindow() and SendMessage() calls to simulate the UI. * **sigh** *)

Comment: An answer that merely links to two other SO questions isn't really an answer. You could do one of two things that would be helpful here: 1) Write an answer that shows how you sent the raw commands (which is what actually answers the question you asked here), or 2) delete the question if it's not worth your time and trouble to do the first.